# Is there a name for such matrices

Tags: matrices, permutations

Let $Z$ be a $K \times K$ matrix. All its left diagonal elements are zero. Further it satisfies the following properties:

1.) $Z[ i ][ j ] = Z[j][i] > 0$ for $1 ≤ i < j ≤ K$.

2.) $Z[i][j]$ belongs to ${1, 2, ... K-2}$ for each $1 ≤ i < j ≤ K$.

3.) For each $r \in {1, 2, ..., K − 2}$, there exist $i, j ∈ \{1, 2, ..., K\}$ such that $Z[i][j] = r$.

4.) $Z[i][j] ≤ \max(Z[i][l], Z[l][j])$ for $1 ≤ i, j, l ≤ N$.

For example $$\quad Z=\left(\begin{matrix}0 &1&2 &2\\1 &0 &2 &2 \\ 2 &2& 0& 2\\ 2& 2& 2& 0\\\end{matrix}\right).$$

Is there any special name for such matrices?

I came across them in my homework on permutations, so I believe they must be common.

I would also be interested in number of such matrices for order K

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices

Comment: @JacobMayle I already went through that, din't find much resemblance.

Comment: What is "left-diagonal."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Z[i][i]=0 for all i belongs to {1, 2, ... K}

Comment: @Salena We usually just call those "diagonal."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes I wrote 'left' to make it more clear, since some people even consider top right to bottom left also as a diagonal.